# PHP Saving Session Variable

Tags: php, variables, session, dynamic

I am trying a new CAPTCHA Script from [here](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/01/a-simple-php-captcha-script/).  To call the CAPTCHA code you use:  **$_SESSION['captcha']['code']**

Well that works when I echo it out on the main form, but when I echo it after the form has been submitted, it displays a new code so I can never find out what the old code was when they submitted the form.

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
    echo $_SESSION['captcha']['code'];
}
```

How can I save that session data and not make it change any more?

Comment: You need verify if your captcha code is rewrite the session variable when the page reload. Probably you'll need make changes on this code.

Comment: You can put here the code that generate and store captcha on session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store it in your own SESSION variable:

```
$_SESSION['old_captcha'] = $_SESSION['captcha'];
```

Then, when the form is submitted, use you own variable:

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
    echo $_SESSION['old_captcha']['code'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put that BEFORE you include the captcha.php again on the next step.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it displays a new code because you come back to the page that displays it. Try submitting to a different page, or maybe not executing the captcha creation code if the session variable is already set.